# contract deployment using brownie and ganache

Tags: python, smartcontracts, ganache, brownie

I want to deploy a contract using `brownie.` after inserting the `brownie run scripts/deploy.py` in the terminal of Pycharm, the following message appeared and nothing else happened. What is the problem?

```
Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID --chainId 1'...
```